# How to link to diffrent types from the same column in MySql

Tags: mysql, database

In a example database I store a reference to different contact addresses for a user.

---

| userid | contactAddress | sendNotification | sendWithDetail |

I would like to store is different types of contact address such as email or a phone number in the contactAddress field. The other fields in the table will remain consistent regardless of type of address, but I do want to be able to put tight validation on all fields.

What are the options to create this in a mySql Database?

I am not in a position to change my database type.

I have scoured google but I think there is a term name that I don't know as I cant make any headway. Any kicks in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question, store a value to indicate type and then the value itself

Comment: Thanks, I haven't done too much work in DB design, so was wondering what the standard would be or if there was something I missed. I presume if I had to store extra data per contact type I would follow the other option I highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

The options I have found (but cant seem to find any more info on) are

- Add an extra field to represent type, and just store the address in a text regardless of type. This makes validation harder but keeps things simple
- Make a different table per type of address, then store the key within the address table. lets you have more fields per type, but will make some complicated key links